# Rails form not invoking create controller method on POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have the following form in my /app/views/password_resets/new.html.erb view

```
<% form_tag password_resets_path do %>
  <label><%= t(:email) %>:</label><br />
  <%= text_field_tag "email" %><br />
  <br />
  <%= submit_tag t("reset_password") %>
<% end %>
```

along with a controller called PasswordResetsController containing a create method:

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if @user
    @user.deliver_password_reset_instructions!
    self.notice = t("password_reset_instructions_are_mailed")
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:error] = t("no_user_found")
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

When I go to /password_resets/new, fill out the form, and submit, the create method is invoked properly, since the PasswordResetsController::create() method is invoked when a POST happens to /password_resets.

However, when I put the form in another view, say, /app/views/test/index.html.erb, fill out the form, an submit, I get

> Unknown action
>
> No action responded to index. Actions:
>   access_forbidden, admin_created?,
>   check_roles, create, edit, find_order,
>   included, new, role_requirements,
>   role_requirements=, title, title=, and
>   update

Any ideas why transplanting the form is not working?

Comment: How did you defined your password_resets_path in your routes?

Comment: What does your server log say when you submit the form (from the other view)?

Comment: @christianblais It's just '/password_resets'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was related to SSL. This showed up in the log:

> Filter chain halted as [:ensure_proper_protocol] rendered_or_redirected.

The page I had the form on required SSL, and Rails did not like me submitting the form from an SSL page to to a non-SSL one. So, as a workaround, since I'm using ssl_requirement, I just put

```
ssl_required :all
```

in the password_resets controller, and now things work.